What is the difference between BeginTextureMode() and DrawTexture in raylib?
Beginner here. I've noticed two approaches to drawing new textures to the screen in raylib, firstly using DrawTexture directly in the drawing stage:
BeginDrawing();
   DrawTexture(texture, posX, posY, WHITE);
EndDrawing();

And another by drawing your Texture2D to a RenderTexture2D before drawing the RenderTexture2D later:
BeginTextureMode(target);
   DrawTexture(texture, posX, posY, WHITE);
EndTextureMode();

BeginDrawing();
     DrawTextureRec(target.texture, (Rectangle) { 0, 0, (float)target.texture.width, (float)-target.texture.height }, (Vector2) { 0, 0 }, WHITE);
EndDrawing();

I've been using both approaches interchangeably without any though put behind it. What is the difference between the two? And how does each one affect performance?

"What is the difference between BeginTextureMode() and DrawTexture"  Typo?  Both of your examples use DrawTexture.

I know, but drawTexture in the context of BeginTextureMode() does not draw to the screen, only to the target. My question was more akin to: "Is there any performance gain to one approach rather than the other?", one approach being to straight up draw every call in BeginDrawing, and another to draw them to a target texture first before drawing them to the screen in DrawTextureRec

I am by no means an expert, but this is how I think it works:
The BeginXX()-functions set modes that change, where the data sent by your draw calls (the DrawXX()-functions) is rendered.
In the BeginDrawing() mode the data sent by your draw calls like DrawTexture() are output to the screen.
In the BeginTextureMode(renderTexture) they are output to a (Render)Texture.
Both modes work with draw calls, which always talk to the GPU (and therefore might be impacting your performance quickly).
It gets interesting when you look at your second example:
You make two draw calls.
First you draw/render a Texture "texture" with DrawTexture() to a Texture "target" and then you render that "target" with DrawTextureRec(target) to the screen.
While you could have saved one draw call by directly rendering to the screen (like you did in your first example), what you effectively did is storing your texture data for future/repeated use.
Imagine you do the above for not only one Texture "texture", but for hundreds or thousands of Textures (eg. tiles of a map):
If you do this with your first method, you send X separate draw calls to the GPU every frame. Even if the Textures are small, communication to GPU is relatively slow, so this likely will impact performance. You want to minimize the amount of draw calls necessary.
If you instead render all of them once (eg. in an init() part) to a Texture "target" (which still requires a lot of draw calls, but only once), you can now send the "target" containing the data of all X Textures to the GPU every frame in a single draw call! This is what GPU's are good at, processing lots of data provided at once.
Obviously, you still have to draw stuff that changes, but the more static your data is (= the less they change), the more sense it makes to buffer/cache stuff with the above concept.
"Chunks" are another topic that work like this: Batching data together to be processed together.
Hope that helps.
Please, if someone knows better, feel free to correct me on anything that might be wrong!
